# Proving the boundary of a set is closed

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove that for any set A $\subset X$ where $(X,d)$ is a metric space, $\partial A$ is closed without using definitions of closure or interior.

I tried to show the equivalent problem of showing that X\ $\partial A$ is open.

$ x\in \partial A \Rightarrow x $ is an interior point of A or an exterior point of A

Assume for a contradiction that $\exists \epsilon > 0 $ s.t. $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \partial A \neq \phi$.
However I am unsure what to do from here to achieve the contradiction.

Comment: **Why** do you want to prove it without using the definitions of closure or of interior?

Comment: They were introduced after the definition of interior point, exterior point and boundary so I am trying to prove this statement without those definitions.

Comment: Use another equivalent fact of a closed set that a set is closed if it contains all its limit points.

Comment: In a topological space $X$, the boundary of a set $A$ is defined as $\overline A\cap \overline{(X\setminus A)}$, and so is necessarily closed as the intersection of closed sets. No need to resort to metrics (and in fact that leads one to a less general, and less useful, result).

Comment: The boundary is defined as the points that are limit points of both $A$ and $A^c$, right?  Note every limit point of the boundary, will have a neighborhood around it that contains a boundary point.  Choose a neighborhood around the boundary point that is entirely within the neighborhood around the limit point. The smaller neighborhood will have a point of $A$ and a point not of $A$ and both are in the neighborhood of the limit point.  So the limit point of the boundary is in the boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ is in $\partial A$ iff

$$\forall \varepsilon>0: (B_\varepsilon(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset) \land (B_\varepsilon(x) \cap A^\complement \neq \emptyset)$$

so logically, $x \notin \partial A$ iff

$$\exists \varepsilon>0: (B_\varepsilon(x) \subseteq A^\complement) \lor (B_\varepsilon(x) \subseteq A)$$

In both cases, any point of $B_\varepsilon(x)$ will also not be in $\partial A$ (as balls are open), so in fact

$$\exists \varepsilon>0: (B_\varepsilon(x)  \subseteq (\partial A)^\complement$$

showing that the complement of the boundary is open, so the boundary is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the usual limit point of the sets of limit points is a limit point of the original set argument.

Let $x$ be a limit point of $\partial A$.  So $B_r(x)$ be any neighborhood of $x$.  And $x$ is a limit point of $\partial A$ there will be a point $a\in \partial A$ so that $a \in B_r(x)$.

Choose a radius $s < r- d(x,a)$ so that $B_s(a) \subset B_r(x)$.  As $a \in \partial A$, $a$ is a limit point of $A$ and a limit point of $A^c$ so there are $y\in A$ and $z\not \in A$ so that $y,z\in B_s(a)\subset B_r(x)$.

So $x$ is a limit point of both $A$ and $A^c$ and so $x \in \partial A$.

So all limit points of $\partial A$ are in $\partial A$ so $\partial A$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a convergent sequence of boundary points, $(x_n)$.  Call a limit $x$.  It suffices to show that $x\in\partial A$.

By definition of limit point, for any open $U_x$ containing $x$, we have $U_x\cap(x_n)\ne\emptyset$.  But then $x_k\in U_x$ for some $k$.

But $x_k$ is a boundary point, hence $U_x\cap A^c\ne\emptyset$ and $U_x\cap  A\ne\emptyset$.

Thus  $x\in\partial A$.

I didn't need the metric at all.